# why final methods are possible to overloaded?

Tags: java

```
class Final
{
    final void methodOne()
    {
       System.out.println("In methodOne");
    }
    void methodOne(int i)//overloaded method
    {
       System.out.println("In overloaded methodOne");
    }
}
```

I know final method can be overloaded.
My question is though using final keyword how it is possible to overload method.
As per the definition of final keyword, " final keyword restricts the further modification. When you use final keyword with an entity (class or variable or method), it gets the meaning that entity is complete and can not be modified further."

Comment: final prevents override, not overload.

Comment: If you overload a function you have two *different* functions, really.

Comment: purpose of final is to prevent overriding not overloading.